# Can't Register a user with drupal Services (Error Response 500 service unavailable)

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-7, user-registration, drupal-services

Using,
        Drupal 7.x,
  Services 3.x.

Everything is working,
    **Login**
    **Getting all nodes**
    **logout**
    **Getting Tokens etc**

Only while registering a new user i get **reponse 500 service unavailable !**

Trying it like this,

**POST method** 
to

> xyz.com/rest/user/register

where rest is the endpoint !

Posting data for registration like this,

```
{
"name":"user343",
"pass":"kes35@r4",
"mail":"user343@sample.com",
"status":"1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by a faulty validation call within the drupal services module.  It is a tough one to track down.  Try a quick patch in the services/resources/user_resource.inc file to fix.

```
diff --git a/resources/user_resource.inc b/resources/user_resource.inc
index 04801fb..7693f2d 100644
--- a/resources/user_resource.inc
+++ b/resources/user_resource.inc
@@ -335,14 +335,6 @@ function _user_resource_create($account) {
   // Execute the register form.
   $form_state['programmed_bypass_access_check'] = FALSE;

-  // Ensure this is validated, as drupal_form_submit will not call validation.
-  user_register_validate('user_register_form', $form_state);
-  $errors = form_get_errors();
-  // If there are errors, then short circuit and return early.
-  if ($errors) {
-   return services_error(implode(' ', $errors), 406, array('form_errors' => $errors));
-  }
-
   drupal_form_submit('user_register_form', $form_state);
   // find and store the new user into the form_state
   if(isset($form_state['values']['uid'])) {
```

If you are uncomfortable with a standard patch, you can just comment out those lines to quickly apply a manual fix. Information sourced from [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2543010#comment-10840768).  Keep enjoying Drupal!